# UPDATE tabela 1 com dados da tabela 2

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados

Bom dia, estou com algumas dificuldades para pegar dados de uma tabela e jogar para outra. Ja tentei INNER JOIN e nao consegui.

Tenho esses dados:

Tabela 1 = nft |
Coluna = walletAdress

Tabela 2 = accounts |
Coluna = wallet

```
UPDATE nft SET nft.walletAddress = accounts.wallet FROM nft INNER JOIN accounts ON nft.account_id = accounts.id WHERE nft.account_id = teste
```

Gostaria de jogar os dados da wallet(tabela 2) para walletAdress(tabela 1) quando account_id = id. Porem meu codigo esta dando erro.

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70). Sempre que edita uma pergunta, ela vai para uma fila de reavaliação e a comunidade decide via voto se já está ok para o site ou não.

Comment: Os comentários se estenderam e foram [movidos para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128858/discussion-on-question-by-curbside-update-tabela-1-com-dados-da-tabela-2) - caso alguém queira acompanhar, basta utilizar o link fornecido.